# XCUITest with PACT not Returning Mock Network Response

Tags: swift, swift3, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, pact

I am attempting to run an XCUITest using [PACT Consumer Swift](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-consumer-swift) and no matter how I try to configure it, a real network request is made instead of receiving the mocked response with a 200 status code and X-Auth-Token. What am I missing?

Here is the UI test case:

```
import XCTest
import PactConsumerSwift
import Nimble

class MyFeature: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()       
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launchArguments = ["FeatureTest"]
        app.launch()
        Nimble.AsyncDefaults.Timeout = 60
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testSuccessfulSignIn() {
        let API = MockService(
            provider: "Sign In API",
            consumer: "Sign In Consumer")

        API
            .given("user signs in with valid credentials")
            .uponReceiving("valid credentials")
            .withRequest(method: .POST,
                path: "/login",
                body: [
                    "username": "john",
                    "password": "1234"
                ])
            .willRespondWith(
                status: 200,
                headers: [
                    "X-Auth-Token":"Super-Cool-Token"
                ])

        API.run { (testComplete) in
            let app = XCUIApplication()

            let usernameField = app.textFields["UsernameField"]
            usernameField.tap()
            usernameField.tap()
            usernameField.typeText("john")

            let passwordField = app.secureTextFields["PasswordField"]
            passwordField.tap()
            passwordField.typeText("1234")

            app.buttons["LOGIN"].tap()

            expect(app.staticTexts["Welcome!"].exists).to(beTrue())

            testComplete()
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the actual login logic:

```
func attemptLogin(_ user:String? = nil, password:String? = nil) -> Promise<LoginResponse> {
    if let
        baseUrl = URLService.getBaseUrl(),
        let url = URL(string: baseUrl + "login")
    {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        if 
            let username = encode(string: user),
            let password = encode(string: password)
        {
            request.httpBody = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        }
    }

    // Sends request and does other stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiating the MockServer class starts up a mock server in the background. The url that it is running on will be available on the MockServer instance. In your example this will be `API.baseUrl`

You need to configure the app under test to talk to this url (i.e. you want `URLService.getBaseUrl()` to be returning the url of the mock server). Maybe you can pass the url in via launch arguments or the environment, e.g. `app.launchArguments = ["FeatureTest", API.baseUrl]`

Comment: Thanks. That did help. We have an xcconfig file that already had the baseUrl the mock server runs under and the UrlService uses to get its base URL. Now my challenge is just getting config conditional variable assignment to work :-/